# Indicate the paragraphs author

Tags: symbols, author

For a thesis which two persons wrote, I need to indicate which paragraph was written by whom. Is there an elegant way to do so?

First I thought about a table of chapters in the back. Then I thought I might rather visualize it on the current page. E.g. with a mark/symbol or whatever next to the section title. How would I do this?

I'm open for any other creative ideas.

EDIT 1:

Some mentioned to use fancyhdr. Got an error with this since I already use this:

```
% Header and footer
\usepackage[automark,footwidth=text,headsepline=0.4pt:head,plainfootsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}  % Custom header and footer
\usepackage{lastpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\setfootsepline{.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chapapp~\thechapter~--~#1}{}}
\ohead{\headmark}
\ofoot[\thepage{} / \pageref{LastPage}]{\thepage{} / \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Can I somehow still use fancyhdr? It's a bit difficult, since my page numbering in the footer and my chapter in the header are switching sides (even/odd). Our initials would have to be on the opposite.

EDIT 2:

Well ... I guess I just came up with a solution. Saw the \ihead{} command and this one actually writes on the opposite of my chapter heading. 
About the concerns what happens if two sections from two authors appear on one page: Since we write or section in different files and include them in the main afterwards, latex makes a new page every time an includes finishes. (Don't know why... but it's quite usefull^^)

Comment: Each paragraph could begin with an `(A)` or `(B)` to indicate the author (with `A` and `B` reflecting actual initials or some other identifying info).  Incidentally, this is the way the US govt marks paragraphs by category, in documents that require it.

Comment: So basically just type my initials in front of echt section title? yeah I mean it would work. Just thought their might be a fancier way.

Comment: You could make it fancier by placing in the margin, using color, etc.

Comment: You could use a page header (for example with the `fancyhdr` package) that shows the author of the current section - however that might be confusing if there are different sections with different authors on a single page.

Comment: @Marijn thats exactly something I was looking for. Had the same concerns. Looks like I might have to avoid pages with sections from two different authors...

Comment: Or do as the ancient Greeks and rewrite your text as a [dialectic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialectic#Classical_philosophy).

Comment: @Marijn But wouldn't you need, in that case, to increase the gap between different authors' paragraphs, inversely proportional to the *dialectic constant*, to prevent ideas from bleeding into adjacent paragraphs? `;^)` (note to self: investigate permittivity of LaTeX glue)

Comment: @Marjin xD interesting, never heard of it. But it might be a bit impracticable. I'd rather test it with fancyhdr. Have you seen my edit? Got some problems.

Comment: you could use `\marginline{}` and put the names as marginal notes. pretty sure, that's uncommon practice and there are smexier ways.

Comment: @naphaneal thank you. Yes I thought the same way. I even removed all my margins. I wan't it somehow subtile. In the margin would look weired I guess..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assortment to choose from.  I have kept markings by paragraph, rather than by page, since that was what was originally indicated by OP.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\mypar{This is a very short paragraph, so that I don't use up
  excessive space in showing different marking techniques.  That is all.}
\begin{document}
(SS) \mypar

(MM) \mypar

\noindent\hrulefill

\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\sffamily\color{blue}\scriptsize SS}\mypar

\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\sffamily\color{red}\scriptsize MM}\mypar

\noindent\hrulefill

\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\color{blue}$\bullet$}\mypar

\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\color{red}$\bullet$}\mypar

\noindent\hrulefill

\mypar

{\slshape \mypar}

\noindent\hrulefill

\leavevmode\color{blue!20!black}\mypar

\leavevmode\color{red!20!black}\mypar
\end{document}
```

[image]

For left-side `\marginpar`s, one might need to change the `\marginparwidth` or right-align the content.  I give a brief MWE below.  Note that these marking should be put into their own macros, as I have EDITED it to do.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\mypar{This is a very short paragraph, so that I don't use up
  excessive space in showing different marking techniques.  That is all.}
\reversemarginpar
\newcommand\authorA{\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\sffamily\color{blue}%
  \makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\scriptsize SS}}}
\newcommand\authorB{\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\sffamily\color{red}%
  \makebox[\marginparwidth][r]{\scriptsize MM}}}
\newcommand\authblue{\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\color{blue}$\bullet$}}
\newcommand\authred{\leavevmode\marginpar{\leavevmode\color{red}$\bullet$}}
\marginparwidth=0pt
\begin{document}
\authorA\mypar

\authorB\mypar

\noindent\hrulefill

\authblue\mypar

\authred\mypar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ou well thanks! Appreciate your suggestions. Especially the second one is nice. I might choose this one.

Comment: @MrMonk3y If you wanted it on the left, the switch `\reversemarginpar` could be set once.  In that case though, you would either want to narrow the width of allocated `\marginparwidth`, or else right-align the particular `\marginpar`s that do this.

Comment: wow you almost knew what I was asking next xD

Comment: @MrMonk3y I have added examples.